# Renaming file extension after uploading to a remote server in WinSCP in batch file

Tags: bash, batch-file, automation, command-line, winscp

I have a script that uploads files to a remote server using WinSCP. The files are processed and deleted by the receiver on the remote server. I would like to upload only new files being written to the local server, and once uploaded, change the file extension from `.txt` to `.csv`. This way, when the script runs again, it will only upload new files with the `.txt` extension, ignoring those that have already been uploaded with the `.csv` extension.

This what I have currently but it won't rename the files on the local server. If I use `ren *.txt *.csv` it will rename them on the remote server.

```
lcd C:\Files
cd /directory

put -filemask="*.txt" -latest -nopreservetime *

lcd C:\Files
!ren *.txt *.csv

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP does not allow you to rename local files.

But you can rename them from your batch file, after WinSCP finishes.

```
cd /D C:\Files

winscp.com /script=upload.txt ...

if errorlevel 0 ren *.txt *.csv
```